# Parcel command not found when I run npm build

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a bundle for openlayers.  I have followed the tutorial https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html When I get to `npm run build` I get the following error.

```
openmap@1.0.0 build /accounts/linuxuser/web_projects/openmap
parcel build --public-url . index.html
sh: parcel: command not found
```

When I `ls` the node_modules folder I get. `parcel -> ../parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js`. 
When I `cd` to the node_modules folder the parcel-bundler folder is not found.  When I run `npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler`  I get the following.

```
  deasync@0.1.15 install /accounts/linuxuser/web_projects/openmap/node_modules/deasync
  node ./build.js
  sh: node: command not found
  openmap@1.0.0 /accounts/linuxuser/web_projects/openmap
```

I do have npm install.

```
npm --version
3.5.2
```

Error after running `npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler`

```
 WARN engine parcel-bundler@1.12.3: wanted: {"node":">= 6.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})

 deasync@0.1.15 install /accounts/linuxuser/web_projects/openmap/node_modules/deasync
 node ./build.js

 sh: node: command not found
 openmap@1.0.0 /accounts/linuxuser/web_projects/openmap
 └── ol@5.3.3  extraneous

 npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
 npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.9
 npm WARN openmap@1.0.0 No description
 npm WARN openmap@1.0.0 No repository field.
 npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-154-generic
 npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "parcel-bundler"
 npm ERR! node v4.2.6
 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
 npm ERR! file sh
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall spawn

 npm ERR! deasync@0.1.15 install: `node ./build.js`
 npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.15 install script 'node ./build.js'.

 pm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the deasync package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     node ./build.js
 npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
 npm ERR!     npm bugs deasync
 npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls deasync
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     /accounts/linuxuser/web_projects/openmap/npm-debug.log
```

The folder structure is

```
   openmap/
       index.html
       index.js
       package.json
       node_modules/
```

Comment: "npm install --save parcel-bundler" - remove that dev from your command and run it and after that run "npm run build"

Comment: did you install node first ?please print the ouput of "node -v" here

Comment: I used the `npm install --save parcel-bundler` command and received the same result.  Yes I have node installed `nodejs -v` outputs v4.2.6 I have to use nodejs because I am using ubuntu

Comment: so in your package.json ->  inside scripts -> build -> instead of node use nodejs

Comment: Here is the build line.  `"build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was running it wrongly, it is suppossed ot be run with either of these commands:

```
npx parcel ...
yarn parcel ...
```